# What Linux command line tool can I use to determine the version and name of a remote DNS?

Tags: linux, command-line, dns

Bind offers you the ability to change the version, name, and hostname as follow:

```
options {
        server-id none;
        hostname none;
        version "Domain Name Server";
};
```

What I'm wondering is: how can I check that information from my Linux command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for `dig`. Specify `id.server`, `hostname.bind`, `version.bind` as the domain name, TXT as rrtype, and [CHAOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaosnet) (or CH) as the class. For example, to query Level3's DNS:

```
$ dig @4.2.2.2 hostname.bind chaos txt

; <<>> DiG 9.13.2 <<>> @4.2.2.2 hostname.bind chaos txt
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49354
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 8192
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;hostname.bind.         CH  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
hostname.bind.      1   CH  TXT "pubntp2.frf1.Level3.net"

;; Query time: 194 msec
;; SERVER: 4.2.2.2#53(4.2.2.2)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 20 09:27:21 EEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 78
```

Comment: Great, that worked with `version.bind` and `hostname.bind`, but the `server-id.bind` doesn't return anything...

Comment: @AlexisWilke: It's `id.server`, a later addition.

Comment: See also [How does one query the resolver name of a DNS server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1119450/how-does-one-query-the-resolver-name-of-a-dns-server)